# inverted indicator constraint in gurobipy

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am a beginner in gurobipy. I would like to add an inverted indicator constraint.

Indicator constraint is nothing but depending on a binary variable a constraint does or does not hold.
In gurobipy this is written as

```
model.addConstr((x == 1) >> (y + z <= 5))
```

where x is a binary variable, y and z are integer variables. This statement says that if x is True then the constraint y+z <= 5 holds.

But I would like to have an inverted constraint like this.
If y+z <= 5 then x == 1. But gurobi does not allow the lhs part of the statement to be an inequality. It can only be a binary variable equal to a constant (0 or 1).

So the inverted statement throws an error.

```
model.addConstr((y + z <= 5) >> (x == 1))
```

Any ideas how to rewrite such a conditional constraint in gurobipy?!

Answer (score 4):

The implication

```
y+z ≤ 5  ⇒  x = 1
```

can be rewritten as:

```
x = 0  ⇒  y+z ≥ 6
```

This can be directly implemented as an indicator constraint.

---

This is based on propositional logic. This is called transposition:

```
A ⇒ B
⇔
not B ⇒ not A
```

So in theory we have

```
y+z ≤ 5  ⇒  x = 1
⇔
x = 0  ⇒  y+z > 5
```

If x and y are integers we can say `x = 0  ⇒  y+z ≥ 6` If they are continuous variables you could do: `x = 0  ⇒  y+z ≥ 5.0001` (in practice I would do: `x = 0  ⇒  y+z ≥ 5` and keep things ambiguous at `y+z = 5`).

This is kind of a standard trick when using indicator constraints. It seems not everyone is aware of or appreciates this.

Comment: This is just the inverse of the inequality. I tried this. But did not work for me

Comment: Mathematically what I do is correct. I assume you implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The indicator syntax is

```
binary expression >> linear constraint
```

So your constraint is invalid.  You need a different model that forces x to 1 when y + z ≤ 5.  Assuming y, z are non-negative integers, try 6x + y + z ≥ 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go with this one is to use the big-M approach
Let reconsider the problem you are trying to model

```
If y+z <= 5 then x == 1
```

It is equivalent to `if y+z-5 <= 0 then x==1`
From here we need a logic that will turn on and off the variable x depending on the condition on the `y+z-5`

```
y + z - 5 <= M(1-x)
```

will do the trick. Note that the x will need to be 1 for the relationship to hold if `y+z-5 <= 0` which is what we want. Similarly, x will be turned off (set to 0) if `y+z-5 >= 0`

I hope this helps